# Libebur128 usage on OS X

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, homebrew

I'm wanting make use of the Libebur128 tool. It's a tool for checking loudness levels of audio files for broadcast compliance.

I've installed via homebrew:

```
brew install libebur128
```

There is however no unix executable so it can't be run by using $ebur128 [audiofile]

I've tried getting the source https://github.com/jiixyj/libebur128 and doing the following;

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

But still no executable.
Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be just a library, not a tool. Note that on the [main github page](https://github.com/jiixyj/libebur128) it says: "For a usage example, see minimal-example.c in the tests folder."

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I presumed, that if it was available via homebrew, it would have an executable.

Comment: Usually anything where the name starts with "lib" is just a library for developers, but in some cases there will also be an executable or a test or demo program too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `libebur128` from CLI (e.g. as a tool), I would recommend checking out [this project](https://github.com/audionuma/r128x) (the `r128x-cli` part).